# Android Studio XML can't outline imageview

Tags: android, xml, layout, background, imageview

I have a Frame layout and an image in said layout, now I want to outline the image in the layout, but when I try to set the background of the ImageView, it just ignores it and fits the canvas, it works in the layoutEditor but for some reason not in the actual app, one thing that I think might be important to know is that the image in the imageview is set by the user so I can't just use an already outlined image.

Thanks in advance for any help.

//Edit

layout-file-code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#000000"
    tools:context=".stickerview.EditActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/COPYRIGHT"
        android:layout_width="108dp"
        android:layout_height="122dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="101dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="151dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="518dp"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.509"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.751"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/COPYRIGHT_best" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/canvas"
        android:layout_width="319dp"
        android:layout_height="342dp"
        android:background="@drawable/image"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/saveBtn"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/cropBtn"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.333"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/shareBtn"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/COPYRIGHT"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0"
        tools:visibility="visible">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/editPresetEdit"
            android:layout_width="318dp"
            android:layout_height="343dp"
            android:background="@drawable/outline"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:visibility="visible"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/backbtn"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/backBtn"
        android:layout_width="53dp"
        android:layout_height="44dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="713dp"
        android:background="@drawable/backbtn"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/buttonBar"
        android:layout_width="333dp"
        android:layout_height="101dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="36dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="477dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="34dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="82dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/buttonbar" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/cropBtn"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="79dp"

        android:layout_marginStart="304dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="485dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="44dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="95dp"
        android:background="@drawable/cropbtn"
        android:text="@string/crop_picture"
        android:textSize="10sp"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/COPYRIGHTBtn"
        android:layout_width="51dp"
        android:layout_height="79dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="255dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="485dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="105dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="95dp"
        android:background="@drawable/textbtn"
        android:text="COPYRIGHT"
        android:textSize="10sp"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/saveBtn"
        android:layout_width="105dp"
        android:layout_height="79dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="151dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="485dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="155dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="95dp"
        android:background="@drawable/textbtn"
        android:text="@string/save"
        android:textSize="19sp"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/textStickerBtn"
        android:layout_width="55dp"
        android:layout_height="79dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="97dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="485dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="259dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="95dp"
        android:background="@drawable/textbtn"
        android:text="@string/text"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/shareBtn"
        android:layout_width="52dp"
        android:layout_height="79dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="45dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="485dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="314dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="95dp"
        android:background="@drawable/sharebtn"
        android:text="@string/share"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/head"
        android:layout_width="445dp"
        android:layout_height="222dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="64dp"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/head"
        tools:visibility="visible" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="336dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="260dp"
        android:text="NiggaButtonV2"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.483"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

and here is the layout I want

[layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eUpAL.png)

Comment: Update your question with the layout file and if possible the design you want ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

```
app:srcCompat="@drawable/COPYRIGHT_best"
```

Use

```
android:src="@drawable/COPYRIGHT_best"
```